# Xamarin.Forms 4: ContentPage's OnBackButtonPressed not called

Tags: xamarin.forms

I tried to override the `OnBackButtonPressed` from my **Xamarin.Forms 4** `ContentPage` as follows

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

but this code is never called from my **Android** device when hardware button is pressed. I already successfully override the software backup button like this:

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}" IconOverride="Back.png" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

But I can get called for the hardware button. In the Main activity I can breakpoint in

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

but not in the `ContentPage`.
Any idea?

Comment: ,I test  at my side, it works fine, the OnBackPressed in Mainactivity and OnBackButtonPressed in contentpage are fired, so what is the Xamarin.forms version, can you post one simple that can reproduce your issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are not receiving your BackButtonPressed event in your ContentPage is because of the Shell navigation. So you will actually be receiving the events in the shell for your BackButtonPressed. So in your Shell class, you will do something like

```
public class AppShell: Shell
{
.
.
 public override void OnBackButtonPressed ()
 {
    base.OnBackButtonPressed ();
 }
```

Feel free to get back in case of queries

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my shell class, I do not have an override for OnBackPressed.
public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell. I use xamarin forms 4.3

Comment: I think this should be available can you quickly recheck this?